# word doc parser

Tags: php, ms-word

Where can I find code for a word document parser preferably in PHP or any other language

Comment: Word 07 or Word 03 or both? The 07 might be simpler to parse because it is essentially a compressed directory with XML files.

Answer (score 0):

For older Word versions there's a shell script which if you can install, you can execute through PHP:

http://www.winfield.demon.nl/